# WARNING: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0

Tags: sass, sass-loader

After I've updated my Angular application, and by doing so also updated Sass compiler I started getting this error

```
$val: 100px;

.some-sellector {
  padding: $val / 2;
}
```

```
WARNING: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart Sass compiler had some changes. Now to use division inside `*.scss` file you need to use the methods: `math.div(value, divider)` or `calc(value / 2)`.

However, I found it easier to use multiplication with decimal number:

```
  padding: $val * 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Gil Epshtain suggested, we can use multiplication as a replacement
but we can use a command to do it for us instead of doing it manually,

**Ref:** https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/2797#issuecomment-878240045

```
$ npm install -g sass-migrator
$ sass-migrator division **/*.scss
```

I used in my project and it's very handy as I'm upgrading from different angular versions.

Hope it helps.